# Ubuntu 14.10 AMD graphics card driver

Tags: amd-gpu, ubuntu-14.10

I'm having some problems with my graphics cards driver and I hoped you guys could help me out. I mispurposeadly changed the x.org's driver to a proprietary one and ended with my computer falling apart with the login loop problem, typical of Thrusty Thar. However, I managed via console to purge the fglrx driver using `sudo apt-get purge` and managed to access the desktop graphically. After that none of the usb ports or sd slot worked, nor did the graphics card, only the ethernet port, so I upgraded Ubuntu Thrusty Thar to Utopical Unicorn with the hope it would fix the driver's problem. It didn't. Can you help me find a solution to my problem? [image: These are my computer's specifications]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst case scenario, you can reinstall Ubuntu. This should fix your issue.

Alternatively, you can upgrade to the latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version and that should have some bug fixes that solve your problem.

I recommend using the open source driver that is already installed and in use when you first install Ubuntu. Only change the open source driver to a proprietary one if there are graphical glitches or other problems with your graphics. I have never had problems with the open source graphics drivers.

Finally, make sure that you install all the available software updates since they may fix some issues too.